# Debugging PHP validation script

Tags: php, validation

I'm building a micro-site, and am having trouble with the password reset behavior.

There is a form that asks the user for their password twice.  I'm not being a password nazi, and the only requirement is that the password be greater than 5 characters.  On submit, the form data is added to the $_POST array and is sent to a setPass function in my site-wide php function script.

The function is

```
function setPass(){
    $link= connectDB();

    $query= "select * from People where Username='" . $_SESSION['name'] . "' Limit 1";
    $result= $link->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows==0){
        $_SESSION['status']= 'invaliduser';
        header("location: ../index.php");
    } else {
        $first = $_POST['firstPass'];
        $second = $_POST['secondPass'];

        if (($first == $second) && (strlen($first) > 5)){
            $password = sha1($first);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm leaving out the database insertion code in this example.

My issue is that this script `echo $_SESSION['name'] . " and password: " . $first;` included in the page body prints out the username, but returns an `unidentified variable: first` warning.  This also happens when I try to access the variable `$password`.

Earlier testing has shown that the first conditional is true, as the page is not redirected.

So what is causing the failure of execution in the else block?

Comment: I don't see an `echo` in your code there... where are you trying to `echo`? Are you doing it inside your `setPass` function or outside?

Comment: I added some HTML header and body tags to the php page where the setPass function is.  That's where the echo tag is.

Comment: Yeah, if you're trying to access those variables outside the `setPass` function then you're out of scope. Use globals or `$_SESSION`, like the answers below.

Comment: @Jason, is there a reason you need the var $first to be set?  If not, all you need is to add `return true;` and `return false;` to get the confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you set `$first` and `$password` inside the `setPass` function, they are not available outside the body of same.

You should use the `global` keyword or, possibly better, return the values from the function if you wish to use them outside.

This concept is called the *scoping* of variables. These variables have *local* scope within the function. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for a comprehensive description of scoping in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you're echoing in the body of the script?  You defined the variable inside a function, so unless you set it as global(generally not a good idea, see [PHP global in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)), $first really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a problem with scopes. You might want to try to use either session or more preferably global variables.

Check this out for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

[EDIT]

Or even better, return $first from the function like Borealid suggested.